# DataTrigger triggered by boolean

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to change the foreground setter property using a boolean equals true.
I tried:

```
public bool RED = false;

if (condition)
   {
    RED = true;
   }
```

and have the DataTrigger triggered by the boolean:

```
     <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
       <Setter Property="Height" Value="16" />
          <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding Path=RED}" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
               </DataTrigger>
              </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
         </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

But no luck. Whats the best/simplest way to write this?

Comment: yes. Im just wanting when boolean=true change foreground color, the simplest way possible.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a property. What you have is a field. Also, you need to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged) or use a [DependencyProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview) or other type type of property that is able to notify a WPF binding.

```
private bool _red;
public bool Red {
    get { return _red; }
    set 
    {
        _red = value;
        OnPropertychanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: @LoganLower: Yeah, assuming your DataContext holds the 'RED' property.